# What can go wrong when using macros as arguments of other macros?

Tags: macros

Thats a problem I encountered several times during the last weeks. I try to use macros as arguments of other macros, and it doesn't work.

The most recent example: I try to use `\addcontentsline` to put a name from a `datatool` database into the table of contents.

*MWE 1:*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{database}

\DTLnewrow{database}
\DTLnewdbentry{database}{shortcut}{JD}
\DTLnewdbentry{database}{name}{John Doe}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%this works and produces the output "John Doe"
\DTLfetch{database}{shortcut}{JD}{name}

%if I use the same command inside \addcontentsline,
%it doesn't work and returns errors
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\DTLfetch{database}{shortcut}{JD}{name}}

\end{document}
```

I'm not (only) asking for a solution to this particular problem, but for a more general explanation what I should consider when using macros as arguments of other macros and what can cause errors when doing so.

I'm sorry if that's a stupid question, but I wasn't able to find any information about that topic, neither in *The LaTeX Companion* nor the internet, although I spent many hours searching.

**EDIT:** Please provide a general answer instead of only solving the problems in the MWEs, if possible. I'd like to understand a bit of what causes those errors and how to avoid them, and I imagine there are many unexperienced users out there who might also find this useful.

To illustrate what kind of problems I'm talking about, here is another MWE with a problem similar to *MWE 1*. I tried to solve it by adding `\protect` randomly on several places (as [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) did in his answer with *MWE 1*, except I guess HE knew what he was doing `;-)` ), but I couldn't make it work in this way.

*MWE 2:*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{database}

\DTLnewrow{database}
\DTLnewdbentry{database}{shortcut}{JD}
\DTLnewdbentry{database}{name}{John Doe}

%command which reads and prints the name belonging to the shortcut
\newcommand{\readname}[1]{\DTLfetch{database}{shortcut}{#1}{name}}

%environment for some text written by the author whose shortcut is in the argument
\newenvironment{authorstext}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%when this line is removed, everything works
    {\textbf{#1} has written this text:}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Authors}

%this doesn't work
\begin{authorstext}{\readname{JD}}
Some text by John Doe.
\end{authorstext}

%this works
\readname{JD}

\end{document}
```

Comment: related: [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5049)

Comment: I added how to deal with MWE2 to my answer

Comment: @egreg Thanks, that solves the two MWEs and already helps me a lot!

Comment: I know you want a general solution rather than one specific to your MWE, but in case anyone is interested in your specific case, I think it's better to write the actual value to the toc (fetching it via, e.g, `\DTLassignfirstmatch`) rather than writing `\DTLfetch` in the toc, as the approach in your MWE results in twice the number of database lookups than is otherwise necessary. For a small number of uses, this isn't too much of a problem, but for large scale use this may significantly slow the document build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that expansion of macros are (during normal processing) mixed with primitive commands and this produces desired output.
But when a parameter is written to the file, it is only expanded but the primitive (and noexpandable) commands are not processed. They are only rewritten to the file. Suppose, you have the macro:

```
\newcount\num  \num=0
\def\macro{\num=113 \ifnum\num=113 YES\else NO\fi}
```

When the `\macro` is processed during normal processing then the primitive command (assigment) sets `\num` to 113 and after that the expansion command `\ifnum` evaluates the conditional as true and `YES` is printed. But now, suppose that the macro is a parameter which is outputted to the file, for example:

```
\num=0
\typeout{\macro}
```

Then `\macro` is expanded, but `\num` is unexpandable command (assignment) which isn't processed now (only reprinted) and `\ifnum` is expandable and it is processed.. The result is

```
\num =133 NO
```

If you process this output later on, the assignemt is processed but the result is `NO`.

Another example. Suppose, that the `\macro` is defined by the following way:

```
\def\macro{...\def\foo{something}...}
```

When normal processing is in progress, then `\macro` expands to `\def\foo{something}` and this primitive command is executed, i. e. the `\foo` si defined. On the other hand, if you try to type `\typeout{\macro}` then
`\def` command isn't processed (it is only rewritten) and `\foo` is expanded. But it is typically undefined so you get Undefinded control sequence error.

Finally suppose that the `\macro` is defined as `\nobreak\space` and `\nobreak` is defined by `\penalty\@M`. Normal processing gives nobreakable space, because `\@M` is defined as a 10000 constant. When you type `\typeout{\macro}` then you get primitive commands and declared constants: `\penalty\@M` followed by expanded space, i.e. invisible space. When you need to read this output again (this is typically done during TOC processing) then you get error `\@` is undefined or it isn't constant (because catcode of `@` is different at this moment). If the catcode of `@` is suitable set then the space is vanished. So there is a problem.

This is a reason why you need to write the `\macro` unexpanded to the file. This can be done by two different way: the `\macro` can be prefixed by `\noexpand` when it is written to the file or it has temporary different meaning (`\relax` for example). LaTeX uses the first method and provides the `\protect` command which expands (contextual dependent) to `\noexpand` or something similar. The `\macro` itself (not the expansion of the `\macro`) is stored to the file. When the contents of the file is read again, the `\macro` is normally processed.

LaTeX provides `\DeclareRobustCommand\macro` which defines `\macro` as `\protect\internal-version-of-macro`. The internal version has the same name but space in the name of the command is appended. I'll not comment this decission of authors of the LaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

`\DTLfetch` is a fragile command and the third argument to `\addcontentsline` is a moving argument. So you want

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\DTLfetch{database}{shortcut}{JD}{name}}
```

The problem is that `\addcontentsline` needs to fully expand its third argument, that might contain data that should be stored with its current value, but might change when the appropriate `\write` instruction is performed (that is, when TeX is shipping out a page), typically a section number.

With `\protect`, a fragile command is protected “forever” from expansion and written as is in the `.toc` file.

On the other hand, `\protect` does nothing when typesetting is involved, so you can solve your more general second problem by defining

```
\newcommand{\readname}[1]{\protect\DTLfetch{database}{shortcut}{#1}{name}}
```