# How to put \varinjlim in the section name?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, errors, symbols, amsmath

Here is (almost) minimal example of the file, which gives the error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Section name with varinjlim: $\varinjlim$}
\end{document}
```

Running pdflatex gives 4 identical errors of the form

```
minimal.tex:5: Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. [...{Section name with varinjlim: $\varinjlim$}]
```

Adding `\tableofcontents` gives 12 additional errors of the form

```
\minimal.toc:2: Only one # is allowed per tab. [...m \p@ \kern -\ex@ }\cr }}}}\nmlimits@ $}{1}]
```

Is there a way to avoid these, and still put `\varinjlim` in the section name?

Comment: it's probably not a "robust" command.  precede it with `\protect` when it's in a "moving" environment (this means anything that may appear somewhere else, such as in the toc, or a running head, or ...).

Comment: the last answer to this question [What can go wrong when using macros as arguments of other macros?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186043/579) explains the theory nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's necessary to use `\protect` or to robustify the command.

However, other problems might appear, if `hyperref` is used, since `pdftex` will complete about invalid strings in bookmarks then. In this case, use `\texorpdfstring` as shown in the second version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Not needed
\begin{document}
\section{Section name with varinjlim: $\protect\varinjlim$}
\section{Section name with varinjlim: \texorpdfstring{$\protect\varinjlm$}{limits}}
\end{document}
```

Another way is to use following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify\varinjlim%
```

This way the `\protect` is not needed, however, it does not prevent the required `\texorpdfstring`.